# Connect Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 to Acer projector

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, screen-sharing

I bought a Samsung Tab 4 8.0 16GB. I want display some videos and documents on the screen through an Acer projector. It has no wifi. How do I display my files?

Is there any possibility?  Tab has no HDMI port. There is a VGA cable for the projector.

Answer (score 0):

The Tab 4 uses MHL via the USB port for video-out.  If you use an MHL HDMI adapter, it'll provide HDMI video out.

Comment: The tab 4 is NOT mhl compatible. It uses wifi to stream or mirror the display. Sorry the 10.1 has wifi and can mirror. Neither is MHL enabled though.